# Ruby on Rails: Organize big search method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have big search method in my model that corresponds to search proper Car.
It looks like this:

```
def self.search(params) 
    cars = joins(:reservations).where.not("reservations.reception_time <= ? AND reservations.return_time >= ?", 
      params[:return_date], params[:handover_date])
    cars = joins(:car_class).where("car_classes.id= ?", params[:car_class])
    cars = cars_at_both_locations(params[:handover_location], params[:return_location])
    cars = params[:car_body_style] == [""] ? cars : joins(:car_configuration).
       where("car_configurations.body_style_id = ?", params[:car_body_style]) 
    cars = params[:car_fuel] == [""] ? cars : where(fuel: params[:car_fuel]) 
    cars = params[:car_transmission] == [""] ? cars : where(transmission: params[:car_transmission]) 
    cars = params [:car_seats] == [""] ? cars : car_seats(params[:car_seats])
    cars = Car.joins(:prices).where('prices.to_days >= ?', 
      (Date.parse(params[:return_date]) - Date.parse(params[:handover_date])).to_i)
  end
```

It is very unreadable...
Did anyone have any idea to refactor this method to be more readable?

Comment: Sounds like a question you should try posting here instead: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank's. I've added a post:
http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/51378/ruby-on-rails-refactor-big-search-method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use scopes with proper names for each method in your Car model

for example for your first two lines, add in your model

```
 scope :available, ->(handover_date,return_date) { joins(:reservations).where.not("reservations.reception_time <= ? AND reservations.return_time >= ?", 
      return_date, handover_date)}
 scope :with_class, ->(car_class_id) {where("car_classes.id= ?", car_class_id)}
```

You will then just have to write

```
def self.search(opts)
  available(opts[:handover_date],opts[:return_date]).
  with_class(opts[:car_class_id]).
 [...]
end
```

You will also be able to use the scopes available and with class everywhere, which is pretty cool too.

Comment: I chnaged this to code to use class methods because they're too long for scopes. Thank's for help.